# Rails: explicitly tell rails the port it's running on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thin

I've got the following problem. I want to explicitly tell rails the port it is running on, so that the _url helper will use that port instead of the autodiscovered port.

The underlying problem is, that I have thin serving my rails app and apache serving static content. This works fine as long as the website is accessed on port 80 (apache) but not when accessed on the port thin is running on. (Which is the port that get's auto discovered.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is supposed to create relative links, which do not include the fully qualified domain name, see example [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), I quote :

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)

# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>;
```

the *_url shortcuts, on the other hand, are using the full path, which is bad when you're behind a reverse proxy (that's apache in your case).

Have you tried using only *_path for links, and *_url for redirects, as, in the case of a redirect, apache should rewrite the url to match its port (assuming you're using the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives at Apache level) ?

If you use url_for, you can force it to be relative by setting the :only_path to true.

If your apache configuration is not based on ProxyPass, could you please copy/paste the interesting part so I can fix this answer ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes _path would fix my problem. However I'm using a gem which uses _url. It's omniauth and it uses _url to send the callback url for an openid authentication. I could of course change the gem, but since it's not really a bug, I would need to stay on a custom build gem for ever which is not ideal. That's why I would simply like to override the port number rails autodiscovers.

Comment: Acutally the _url is not called by omniauth, but by the oauth gem. But the problem stays the same.

Comment: That's quite a lot of informations that would have been nice to find in the original question : thin, apache, _url being called from outside your code by oauth. Anyway, if omniauth/oauth don't offer the possibility to modify the callback url, maybe you should contact their authors and see if they have a solution for you ? If not, they might include it in a future version. By the way, I think Devise does highjack the oauth url to replace it, maybe you can look that way too.

Answer (score 0):

Because Ruby on Rails uses its own server, users visiting your website (and subsequently your Ruby on Rails application) will need to be redirected to the appropriate port.

To change the port of Ruby on Rails server you should start the server with the -p option:

```
ruby s -p <port-number>
```

Comment: you probably want `rails s -p <port>`

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. As indicated, the configuration is working fine as long as users enter the website using port 80 (apache). What I want to to is tell Rails - which is running on a different port - that it should use port 80 when the _url helper is called. Apache makes sure that thin responses when the rails application is called.